# Using Java JAR file in .NET

Tags: java, .net, jar, managed

What options / methods / software are available to convert a JAR file to a managed .NET assembly?
Please provide all commercial and non-commercial methods in the answer.
These don't include solutions which require Java to be installed on the host machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that's impossible. The java byte code is different to the code produced to run on the CLR.

**Snarky answer**: Get the source code, and port it.

EDIT: A little poking comes up with http://sourceforge.net/projects/ikvm/, a Java Virtual Machine implementation for .NET. Not quite what you asked for, but it's probably going to be the best you can do.

Comment: snarky is ok.  the question begs it.

Comment: bytecode is rewriteable, the hard part is the runtime classes

Answer (score -1):

Confronted with this situation last year, I wrote a small wrapper (in java) that read the inputs from a temp file, invoked the jar and placed the output in anther temp file. The .NET project would create the input file, call the JVM and start the wrapper, wait for it to finish and read the output file. Quick and Dirty. at least in my case

Comment: Although this approach clearly works, I would VERY heavily discourage such approaches and would promote some RPC mechanism instead.