# Using a jar file in .net core application

Tags: c#, jar, .net-core, multiplatform

Have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108/using-java-jar-file-in-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683257/using-java-jar-package-in-asp-net-4-0-application) where it gives the same solution of mono project, I don't want to use third party want to use a .net core solution. I will be creating a new C# .net core project but am bound to use tens of jars, which of course I cant port to .net.

So want to know is there a way to use a jar in a .net core project

Comment: I assume you don't mean jar, you mean the Java bytecode inside them. Directly it is not possible because it's completely different platform.

Comment: ok understand that, so that will not be possible?

Comment: You could probably use process' to run them, and you can get command line output by reading the processoutput, but other than that there is no direct functionality available to hook a jar into your .NET application.